# Ajuda para enviar inputs clonados por jQuery para o banco de dados

Tags: php

Eu tenho um formulário que irá adicionar links de servidores de download para um arquivo, porém, cada arquivo pode conter **n** links de servidores de download

Em HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="server_down">
```

Esse input é clonado por um jQuery para que o usuário possa adicionar outras opções de servidores se o arquivo possuir mais de um servidor de distribuição, então eu fiz algo assim:

```
<input type="text" name="server_down_1">
<input type="text" name="server_down_2">
<input type="text" name="server_down_n">
```

Sempre que o usuário clona o input, o último valor soma 1.
Porém, pra enviar pro banco de dados eu preciso fazer um loop baseado na quantidade de elementos que eu clonei, e pra isso eu fiz um input auxiliar da seguinte maneira

```
<input type="hidden" name="field_clonada" value="Quantas vezes foi clonada">
```

Dessa maneira eu consigo salvar no banco de dados sem problema, mas o que eu gostaria de saber é se existem maneiras mais "eficientes" de se fazer isso, ou quais são as outras formas de fazer isso?

O Loop em PHP que uso para processar os dados é esse:

```
<?php $count = $_POST['field_clonada'];
for ($i=1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
   salva_no_bd($arq_id, 'server_down_'.$i, $_POST['server_down_'.$i]);
}
```

Comment: Basta fazer `name="server_down[]"`, com os colchetes e no PHP fazer `$_POST['server_dow']` para obter o *array*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em vez de enumerar o `name`, o que é mais complicado, você pode usar o `name` como array adicionando colchetes:

```
name="server_down[]"
```

Os valores serão enviados ao PHP em forma de array, onde você pode fazer um `foreach` para pegar os valores:

```
$server_down = $_POST['server_down'];
foreach($server_down as $key => $i){
   salva_no_bd($arq_id, 'server_down_'.$key, $i);
}
```

O `$i` é o valor de cada campo na array. O `$key` retorna o índice dos itens na array, começando do 0.

Veja se era isso mesmo, porque não entendi bem o `'server_down_'.$count`, onde você concatena a quantidade dos itens. Se for isso mesmo que deseja, altere para:

```
$server_down = $_POST['server_down'];
$count = sizeof($server_down);
foreach($server_down as $key => $i){
   salva_no_bd($arq_id, 'server_down_'.$count, $i);
}
```

O `sizeof($server_down)` retorna o número de elementos na array.

Comment: Ops, peço desculpas pelo meu engano, eu estava escrevendo o código de exemplo e acabei me equivocando, eu vi a sua primeira resposta e está exatamente perfeita pra pergunta que eu fiz, mas como era um engano e você rapidamente notou e corrigiu, e agora além de me corrigir, é a solução correta pra pergunta.

Comment: Eu ainda recomendaria unir esses valores em uma só SQL e enviar tudo de uma vez para o banco, assim executando apenas 1 vez e não N vezes.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Poderia exemplificar esse método? Seria usando o método de serialização de dados? o serialize() ?

Comment: @Heathcliff Ao invés de executar `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...)` N vezes, você pode fazer `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...), (...), (...), ..., (...)` já enviando todos os valores.