# Como faço para pegar vários dados digitados e salvar em um array em php

Tags: php

Como faço para pegar vários dados digitados de uma caixa de texto em html e depois lançar em um array em PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue o código:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="texto[]">
    <input type="text" name="texto[]">
    <input type="text" name="texto[]">
    <input type="text" name="texto[]">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

print_r($_POST['texto']);

}
?>
```

Você usa o `<input name="valor[]">` O "`[]`" serve pra transformar o input em um array :)

Dúvida tirada pelo @SAM no post:
[Ajuda para enviar inputs clonados por jQuery para o banco de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/402441/ajuda-para-enviar-inputs-clonados-por-jquery-para-o-banco-de-dados)